# My Window forms keeps resetting to its default values each time I hide it

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I need to create a simple inventory system without a database.
However, my forms keep resetting to its default value after hiding them and showing them.

I tried restructuring my code several times and using this.visibility instead of this.show

```
    //Code for my main window
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddTransactionWindow AddTransWindow = new AddTransactionWindow();
        AddTransWindow.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Inventory OpenInventory = new Inventory();
        OpenInventory.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

//Code for my inventory window

```
public partial class Inventory : Window
{
    public Inventory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool positiveNumbericalInput = true;
        string selectedJewelry;
        int amountAdded;
        //object selectedJewelry = cmbTypeofJewelry.SelectedItem;
        //Object selectedItem = cmbTypeofJewelry.SelectedItem;
        selectedJewelry = cmbTypeofJewelry.Text;

        if (txtAmount.Text == "")
        {
            positiveNumbericalInput = false;
            txtAmount.Text = "0";
        }

        amountAdded = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);

        if (positiveNumbericalInput)
        {
            int existingAmount;
            switch (selectedJewelry)
            {
                case "Diamond":
                    existingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amntDiamond.Text);
                    existingAmount = existingAmount + amountAdded;
                    amntNecklace.Text = existingAmount.ToString();
                    break;

                case "Pink Diamond":
                    existingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amntPinkDiamond.Text);
                    existingAmount = existingAmount + amountAdded;
                    amntEarrings.Text = existingAmount.ToString();
                    break;

                case "Sapphire":
                    existingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amntSapphire.Text);
                    existingAmount = existingAmount + amountAdded;
                    amntRing.Text = existingAmount.ToString();
                    break;

                case "Emerald":
                    existingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amntEmerald.Text);
                    existingAmount = existingAmount + amountAdded;
                    amntBracelet.Text = existingAmount.ToString();
                    break;
            }

            //MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedJewelry + "\n" + "Amount Added: " + amountAdded);
        }
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmbTypeofJewelry.Items.Add("Diamond");
        cmbTypeofJewelry.Items.Add("Pink Diamond");
        cmbTypeofJewelry.Items.Add("Sapphire");
        cmbTypeofJewelry.Items.Add("Emerald");
    }

    private void Return_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        OpenMain.Show();
    }

    private void cmbTypeofJewelry_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

This code can change the text in the textblocks but, after hiding it and making it visible again. The texts defaults to its original values.

Comment: `new Inventory()` creates a *new* Inventory instance. Setting its Visibility to Visible does not set the Visibility of any other, previously created instance.

Comment: Oh. So that means that i'm opening a new window each time right? Instead of reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the OpenInventory declaration to your form as:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Inventory OpenInventory;
```

in the contructor of your form instantiate the OpenInventory:

```
public Form1()
{
    OpenInventory = new Inventory();
```

remove the code from the Botton_Click.

Comment: Should I be doing the same for my Inventory Form?

Comment: I do not think it is needed. You have the think about it like data in memory. So you can have an object what holds data instantiated in the main class or form for that matter. If you have more than one form, you should use the main class and pass the object on to the form by contructor of the form like: public Form1 (Inventory MyInventory).

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions may seem basic as I just began learning programming but, how do I reopen my Main Window when I am in my inventory form without doing the "Main OpenMain = new Main()"

Comment: For me they are. Reopen is like setting it as you did: new Main(). Where .Show() is showing the form and .BringToFront() is having it as first form of the Z-Order stack.

Comment: I guess what I meant was Reopen. Moreover, the code ran fine but, pressing the return button from my inventory and opening it again still reset my text blocks to its original values.

Comment: You need to go one level higher (your question: Should I be doing the same for my Inventory Form?). The answer is yes :-) on the main form add private object for inventory. I have the feeling you are still having too much new.. in your code but you will need to check yourself.

Comment: Yeah i'm quite new to OOP :/ . What does "private object" do exactly once I add it?

Comment: private means it is only accessable from within the parent object, in your case the main form.